# Is there a way to access props outside methods in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

```
<script lang='ts'>
import GraphWorld from '@/components/GraphWorld.vue'
//  import { defineComponent } from "vue"
export default {
  name: 'GraphView',
  props: ['people', 'prac'],
  components: {
    GraphWorld
  },
  setup() {
    const nodes={}
    const edges={}
    const n= 5
    //  var x = this.prac
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    nodes[`node${i}`] = {
    name: `Node ${i}`
  };
}
    for (let i=1;i<=n-1;i++){
      edges[`edge${i}`]={
        source:`node${i}`,
        target:`node${i+1}`
      }
    }    
    return { nodes, edges }
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
```

I want to use "prac" in **setup()**, basically prac is a json and I want to iterate through it to create the nodes and edges.
Is there a way to do that, I tried directly using *this.prac* inside setup(), but that gave me an error. I also tried moving setup() inside the method but that is causing other problems.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT:
The following finally worked perfectly:

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'
import GraphWorld from '@/components/GraphWorld.vue'
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
export default defineComponent ({
  name: 'GraphView',
  props: ['people', 'prac'],
  components: {
    GraphWorld
  },
  setup(props) {
    const nodes={}
    const edges={}
    const { prac } = toRefs(props)
    const n = reactive( prac.value )
    //  const n= prac.length
    for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    nodes[`node${i}`] = {
    name: `${n[i].Organizations}`
  },
  nodes[`node${i+n.length}`] = {
    name: `${n[i].Title}`
  };
}
    for (let i=0;i<n.length;i++){      
      edges[`edge${i}`]={
        source:`node${i}`,
        target:`node${i+n.length}`
      }
    }   
    return { nodes, edges }
  }
```

Comment: You aren't supposed to use `methods` with setup at all. You don't have `this` there either. Just use `props` param as shown in composition api examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your props within `setup()` by using the `props` argument like this :

```html
<script lang='ts'>
import GraphWorld from '@/components/GraphWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'GraphView',
  props: ['people', 'prac'],
  components: {
    GraphWorld
  },
  setup(props) {
    const prac = props.prac
    // use your props here
    return {}
  }
}
</script>
```

[see more here](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-props)

Comment: Thank you for the solution.
I tried your solution but it gave another error then I tried what given on the composition API website
```const { prac } = toRefs(props)
    const n= prac.length
```
Now I am getting ```Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Ref<any>'.```
What am I doing incorrectly?
I want to use prac to iterate over it.

Comment: Never Mind I figured it out,
Thank you very much for your help.